# Watch for changes in local folder and upload them to SFTP server

Tags: powershell, scripting, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

Linux user here trying to write a script in PowerShell to automate SFTP transfers from a Windows server to a remote server. I have everything working for the most part (though I still have some testing to do). My current issue is after the script runs one time it is done. I need the `FileSystemWatcher` to run every time it finds a new file creation. I realize this is because of the `exit` but when I remove that portion and a user drops in a directory it loops through every file in the directory and uploads every file in the directory over and over. What I need it to do is run through the process once and then remain active to listen for another file creation event. My issue may be my limited workings with coding in Windows so any help is appreciated!

And yes I realize the duplication of code in the handling of my files vs my folders is redundant. I will most likely make that portion a function that accepts parameters depending on if it is given a file or folder.

I am posting my entire code in case it can help someone later

```
###Watches a directory for new files and fires off the batch file to push to Connexxion

$folder = "C:\pathTo\watchfolder"
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $folder
$watcher.Filter  = "*.csv"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

### LISTEN FOR CREATE
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$folderpath = $(split-path -LiteralPath $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)
$filename = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$filepath = (Join-Path $folderpath $filename.split("\")[-1])

Write-Host folderpath: $folderpath
Write-Host filename: $filename
Write-Host filepath: $filepath 

$remotePath = "/data/"

If($filename.contains("\")){
  Write-Host "Here is directory"
  try 
  {
    #Set path to winscp 
    $assemblyPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $assemblyPath "WinSCPnet.dll")

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = "hostname"
        UserName = "username"
        Password = "passwd"
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx"
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
      # Connect
      $session.Open($sessionOptions)
      # Upload files, collect results
      $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
      $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

      $transferResult =
          $session.PutFiles($folderpath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions)

      # Throw on any error
      $transferResult.Check()

      # Print results
      foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
      {
          Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      # Disconnect, clean up
      $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
  }#end of first try 
  catch
  {
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
  }
}
Else{
  Write-Host "Here is a file"
  try 
  {
    #Set path to winscp 
    $assemblyPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $assemblyPath "WinSCPnet.dll")

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = "hostname"
        UserName = "username"
        Password = "passwd"
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx"
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
      # Connect
      $session.Open($sessionOptions)
      # Upload files, collect results
      $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
      $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

      $transferResult =
          $session.PutFiles($filepath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions)

      # Throw on any error
      $transferResult.Check()

      # Print results
      foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
      {
          Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      # Disconnect, clean up
      $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
  }#end of first try 
  catch
    {
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
    }
  }

}#end of action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the path to the new file and use [`RemotePath.TranslateLocalPathToRemote`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotepath_translatelocalpathtoremote) to map it to a server path, and upload the file there.

The code will be a lot simpler. All you need to do is to make sure new folders are re-created on the server.

```
# Watches a directory for new files and
# fires off the batch file to push to connection

$remotePath = "/data"
$localPath = "C:\pathTo\watchfolder"
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $localPath
$watcher.Filter  = "*.csv"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $True
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $True

### LISTEN FOR CREATE
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
    try
    {
        $localFilePath = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        Write-Host "Local path: $localFilePath"

        $assemblyPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
        Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $assemblyPath "WinSCPnet.dll")

        # Setup session options
        $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
            Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
            HostName = "example.com"
            UserName = "username"
            Password = "password"
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
        }

        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

        try
        {
            $remoteFilePath =
                [WinSCP.RemotePath]::TranslateLocalPathToRemote(
                    $localFilePath, $localPath, $remotePath)
            Write-Host "Remote path: $remoteFilePath"

            # Connect
            $session.Open($sessionOptions)

            # Check if corresponding remote directory exists, if not, create it
            $i = $remoteFilePath.LastIndexOf("/")
            $remoteDirPath = $remoteFilePath.SubString(0, $i)
            if (($remoteDirPath.Length -gt 0) -and
                !$session.FileExists($remoteDirPath))
            {
                Write-Host "New subdirectory, creating $remoteDirPath on server"
                $session.CreateDirectory($remoteDirPath)
            }

            $session.PutFiles($localFilePath, $remoteFilePath).Check()

            Write-Host "Upload of $localFilePath succeeded"
        }
        finally
        {
            # Disconnect, clean up
            $session.Dispose()
        }

    } #end of first try 
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
} #end of action


while ($True) { sleep 5 }
```