# Move local files to another local directory after powershell script SFTP file watcher exchange

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, file-watcher

This is the script I'm using at the moment for file watching and uploading found here:

[Watch for changes in local folder and upload them to SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682702/watch-for-changes-in-local-folder-and-upload-them-to-sftp-server?newreg=77ee8376a54c48cd80c1bee25c727b37)

How can I add in the function to move the local files to another local directory after successful SFTP upload?

```
# Watches a directory for new files and
# fires off the batch file to push to connection

$remotePath = "/data"
$localPath = "C:\pathTo\watchfolder"
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $localPath
$watcher.Filter  = "*.csv"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $True
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $True

### LISTEN FOR CREATE
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
    try
    {
        $localFilePath = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        Write-Host "Local path: $localFilePath"

        $assemblyPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
        Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $assemblyPath "WinSCPnet.dll")

        # Setup session options
        $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
            Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
            HostName = "example.com"
            UserName = "username"
            Password = "password"
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
        }

        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

        try
        {
            $remoteFilePath =
                [WinSCP.RemotePath]::TranslateLocalPathToRemote(
                    $localFilePath, $localPath, $remotePath)
            Write-Host "Remote path: $remoteFilePath"

            # Connect
            $session.Open($sessionOptions)

            # Check if corresponding remote directory exists, if not, create it
            $i = $remoteFilePath.LastIndexOf("/")
            $remoteDirPath = $remoteFilePath.SubString(0, $i)
            if (($remoteDirPath.Length -gt 0) -and
                !$session.FileExists($remoteDirPath))
            {
                Write-Host "New subdirectory, creating $remoteDirPath on server"
                $session.CreateDirectory($remoteDirPath)
            }

            $session.PutFiles($localFilePath, $remoteFilePath).Check()

            Write-Host "Upload of $localFilePath succeeded"
        }
        finally
        {
            # Disconnect, clean up
            $session.Dispose()
        }

    } #end of first try 
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
} #end of action


while ($True) { sleep 5 }
```

I've tried to cobble in this function, but it won't work:

```
  # Upload files, collect results
        $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath)
 
        # Iterate over every transfer
        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            # Success or error?
            if ($transfer.Error -eq $Null)
            {
                Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded, moving to backup"
                # Upload succeeded, move source file to backup
                Move-Item $transfer.FileName $backupPath
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) failed: $($transfer.Error.Message)"
            }
```

Comment: Although your code is unnecessarily complicated, it should work. Unless you have the variables really named as wrongly as the question suggestes (in the first code you have `$localFilePath`/`$remoteFilePath`, while in the latter you have `$localPath`/`$remotePath` in the same context). Anyway, *"won't work"* won't work as a problem description. We need much more detailed problem description, if you need our help.

Comment: This code is an answer I found of yours in a previous question. The file watcher & transfer works fine. I'm having trouble adding the function to move the files after the sftp upload. 

The second code was a function I found in a separate thread, but I'm unsure of how to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"implement"*? You have everything you need (although the code can be simplified). You just need to use the same variable names.

Comment: I do not know how to add the additional code to the original.

Comment: Just below ` Write-Host "Upload of $localFilePath succeeded"`
```
            #move into local folder after success
            Move-Item $localFilePath $backupPath```

Comment: But you do not want to have two `$session.PutFiles` calls! So not *"just below"*, but **instead** the `$session.PutFiles($localFilePath, $remoteFilePath).Check()` `Write-Host "Upload of $localFilePath succeeded"`